# AWS S3 MFA delete for non-root users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

As it was already answered in other questions, only the bucket owner (root user) can enable/disable MFA delete, using the cli.

I was not able to find an answer however on if there is a way for the bucket owner to grant permissions to other non-root users to perform permanent deletions of specific versions, using their own MFA codes, or if this is something that only the bucket owner can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if there is a way for the bucket owner to grant permissions to other non-root users to perform permanent deletions of specific versions

No. MFA delete is only for the root.

Comment: How does this work with Organization Member Account? Each account has it's own root user and you have to go out of your way to reset the root user password for each account.